# Photon Unity - How to make game run only after both players have selected their moves

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, photon

I am building a game where both players need to select their position and move, then a battle simulation will take place. I have 3 scripts: 
1. Player Network
2. Player Management
3. Player Movement

For step one, I am not sure how to make it such that, when a player click on the map, he store the x and y transform and sends a msg to the server that he is ready.

Server checks if both players are ready, if yes, it moves both players to their respective x and y position. If i can get this logic done, I will be able to figure out the rest of the logic I am sure.

Player Network Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.IO;


public class PlayerNetwork : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerNetwork Instance;
    public string PlayerName {get; private set;}
    private PhotonView photonView;
    private int playersInGame;
    private PlayerMovement2 CurrentPlayer;

    //Position to spawn the players
    private Vector3 spawnPosition1 = new Vector3(3.5f,0f,0.5f);
    private Vector3 spawnPosition2 = new Vector3(3.5f,0f,7.5f);
    private bool secondPlayer;


    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
        photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();

        PlayerName = "Ash" + Random.Range(10,99);
        playersInGame = 0;
        secondPlayer = false;

        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneFinishedLoading;
    }

    private void OnSceneFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) {                           //when the battle starts
        if(scene.name == "Battle"){
            if(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
                MasterLoadedGame();
            else
                NonMasterLoadedGame();
        }
    }

    private void MasterLoadedGame() {
        photonView.RPC("RPC_LoadedGameScene", RpcTarget.MasterClient, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer);
        photonView.RPC("RPC_LoadGameOthers", RpcTarget.Others);
    }

    private void NonMasterLoadedGame() {
        photonView.RPC("RPC_LoadedGameScene", RpcTarget.MasterClient, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer);
    }

    [PunRPC]                                                    //to allow method to contact other players
    private void RPC_LoadGameOthers() {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(5);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void RPC_LoadedGameScene(Player photonPlayer) {
        PlayerManagement.Instance.AddPlayerStats(photonPlayer);
        secondPlayer = true;
        playersInGame++;
        if(playersInGame == PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length){
            photonView.RPC("RPC_CreatePlayer", RpcTarget.All);
        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void RPC_CreatePlayer() {

        Vector3 rot;
        Vector3 spawnPosition;
        GameObject obj;
        int y;

        if(!secondPlayer){
            spawnPosition = spawnPosition1;
            y=0;
            rot = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
        } else {
            spawnPosition = spawnPosition2;
            y=7;
            rot = new Vector3(0f,180f,0f);
        }

        obj = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("Prefabs","Playerv2"), spawnPosition, Quaternion.Euler(rot), 0);
        BoardManager.Instance.AddPlayerBoard(obj,3,y);
        GameButtons.Instance.UpdatePlayerButtons(obj);
        CurrentPlayer = obj.GetComponent<PlayerMovement2>();

    }


    public void NewHealth(Player photonPlayer, int health){
        photonView.RPC("RPC_NewHealth", photonPlayer, health);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void RPC_NewHealth(int health){
        if(CurrentPlayer == null)
            return;

        if(health <= 0) {
            PhotonNetwork.Destroy(CurrentPlayer.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void InformServer_PlayerMoved(int x, int y) {
        photonView.RPC("RPC_InformServer_PlayerMoved", RpcTarget.All, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer, x, y);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void RPC_InformServer_PlayerMoved(Player photonPlayer, int x, int y) {
        PlayerManagement.Instance.UpdatePlayerAttack(photonPlayer, x, y);
    }


    public void RunAttackSimulation(){
        photonView.RPC("RPC_RunAttackSimulation", RpcTarget.All);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    private void RPC_RunAttackSimulation(){
        PlayerManagement.Instance.Battle();
    }
}
```

Player Management Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.IO;

public class PlayerManagement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerManagement Instance;
    private PhotonView PhotonView;
    public int countPlayersReady = 0;
    public Text Xpos_text, Ypos_text;

    private List<PlayerStats> PlayerStats = new List<PlayerStats>();            //holds information on all players

    void Awake() {
        Instance = this;
        Xpos_text = GameObject.Find("Xpos").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        Ypos_text = GameObject.Find("Ypos").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    }
    void Start() {
        Xpos_text.text = " "+0;
        Ypos_text.text = " "+0;
    }

    public void AddPlayerStats(Player photonPlayer){                            //called everytime a player loads into the scene
        int index = PlayerStats.FindIndex(x => x.PhotonPlayer == photonPlayer);
        if(index == -1) {
            PlayerStats.Add(new PlayerStats(photonPlayer, 30));
        }
    }

    public void ModifyHealth(Player photonPlayer, int value){
        int index = PlayerStats.FindIndex(x => x.PhotonPlayer == photonPlayer);     //check who's health you need to change
        if(index != -1){
            PlayerStats playerStats = PlayerStats[index];
            playerStats.Health += value;
            PlayerNetwork.Instance.NewHealth(photonPlayer, playerStats.Health);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateXandY(Player photonPlayer, int x, int y){
        int index = PlayerStats.FindIndex(j => j.PhotonPlayer == photonPlayer);
        if(index != -1){
            PlayerStats playerStats = PlayerStats[index];
            playerStats.newX = x;
            playerStats.newY = y;
            Xpos_text.text = "XPos: " + playerStats.newX;
            Ypos_text.text = "YPos: " + playerStats.newY;
        }
    }


    public void ReadyToAttack(Player photonPlayer) {
        Debug.Log(photonPlayer + " is ready to attack called");
        int index = PlayerStats.FindIndex(j => j.PhotonPlayer == photonPlayer);
        if(index != -1){
            PlayerStats playerStats = PlayerStats[index];
            PlayerNetwork.Instance.InformServer_PlayerMoved(playerStats.newX, playerStats.newY);
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePlayerAttack(Player photonPlayer, int x, int y) {             //this function only called on server
        Debug.Log("Updating Player's attack");
        int index = PlayerStats.FindIndex(j => j.PhotonPlayer == photonPlayer);     //check which player played
        if(index != -1){
            PlayerStats playerStats = PlayerStats[index];
            playerStats.currX = x;                                                 //changes made on server at this point
            playerStats.currY = y;
            if(!playerStats.Ready){
                playerStats.Ready = true;
                countPlayersReady++;
            }

            if(countPlayersReady == 2) {
                Debug.Log("both players made their move, run attack simulation");
                PlayerNetwork.Instance.RunAttackSimulation();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Battle() {
        Debug.Log("Battle working");

        foreach(PlayerStats p in PlayerStats){
            Debug.Log(p.PhotonPlayer + "move to... Xpos: " + p.currX + " and Ypos : " + p.currY);            
        }



        //change curr position of players in Player Stats and make the new x and y back to null
        /*PlayerStats[0].currX = newX;
        PlayerStats[0].currY = newY; */


        countPlayersReady = 0;
    }
}


public class PlayerStats {
    public PlayerStats(Player photonPlayer, int health){
        PhotonPlayer = photonPlayer;
        Health = health;
    }

    public readonly Player PhotonPlayer;
    public int Health;
    public bool Ready = false;
    public int newX;
    public int newY;
    public int currX;
    public int currY;
}
```

PlayerMovement Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

    public class PlayerMovement2 : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
    {
        private PhotonView photonView;
        public Camera playerCamera;
        private int selectionX = -1;
        private int selectionY = -1;
        public bool isPlayerTurn = true;
        public GameObject movePrefab;
        private Transform Position;

        private PositionGet selectedPlayer;
        private Vector3 offsetCamera = new Vector3(0,10,-10);

        //Selected Position
        public int posX;
        public int posY;


        void Awake() {
            photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
            if(photonView.IsMine){
                playerCamera.enabled = true;
            }
            Position = GetComponent<Transform>();
        }

        void Start() {
            selectedPlayer = GetComponent<PositionGet>();
            if(selectedPlayer == null) {
                Debug.Log("error getting positionGet class of playerv1 script");
            } else {

            }
            posX = (int)(transform.position.x - 0.5);
            posY = (int)(transform.position.y - 0.5);
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            DrawChessBoard();
            if(photonView.IsMine){
                UpdateSelection();                                      //Updates X and Y Coordinate
                if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
                    if(!isPlayerTurn)
                        return;
                    if(selectionX >= 0 && selectionY >= 0){
                        posX = selectionX;
                        posY = selectionY;
                        PlayerManagement.Instance.UpdateXandY(photonView.Owner, posX, posY);
                        MovePlayer(posX, posY);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdateSelection() {
            if(!playerCamera) {                         //if no camera object
                Debug.Log("playerCamera not found");
                return;
            }

            RaycastHit hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 25.0f, LayerMask.GetMask("BoardPlane"))){
                selectionX = (int)hit.point.x;
                selectionY = (int)hit.point.z;
            }
            else {
                selectionX = -1;
                selectionY = -1;
            }
        }



        private void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info) {
            if(stream.IsWriting){
                stream.SendNext("X-coordinate");
                stream.SendNext("Y-coordinate");
            }
            else {
                selectionX = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
                selectionY = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
            }
        }

        private void DrawChessBoard() {
            Vector3 widthLine = Vector3.right * 8;                  //depending how big you want the map
            Vector3 heightLine = Vector3.forward * 8;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++ ) {
                Vector3 start = Vector3.forward * i;
                Debug.DrawLine(start, start + widthLine);
                for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++ ){
                    start = Vector3.right * j;
                    Debug.DrawLine(start, start + heightLine);
                }
            }

            //Draw Selection
            if(selectionX >= 0 && selectionY >= 0 ) {
                Debug.DrawLine(
                    Vector3.forward * selectionY + Vector3.right * selectionX,
                    Vector3.forward * (selectionY + 1) + Vector3.right * (selectionX + 1));

                Debug.DrawLine(
                    Vector3.forward * (selectionY + 1) + Vector3.right * selectionX,
                    Vector3.forward * selectionY + Vector3.right * (selectionX + 1));
            }
        }

        public void MovePlayer(int x, int y) {
            transform.position =  transform.position = new Vector3 ((float)x, transform.position.y, (float)y);
        }


    }
```

Comment: what is your code doing wrong so far? do you have any error log?

Comment: Code is working fine, But I am stuck at the line => PlayerManagement => Battle() => I don't know how to get both the players to move based on their inputs.

Comment: Hi @AashwiinRoghan, Thank you for choosing Photon! To learn how to move player/character based on input, check out Unity tutorials official or on YouTube, if you want to synchronize this, either use PUN's PhotonView or check out other tutorials online on how to do this using PUN. We strongly suggest starting with [PUN Basics Tutorial](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/demos-and-tutorials/pun-basics-tutorial/intro).

Comment: there is also an issue in your question itself:
title: "Photon Unity - How to make game run only after both players have selected their moves"
and
" If i can get this logic done, I will be able to figure out the rest of the logic I am sure."
vs
"Code is working fine"